# symfony performance with voters

Tags: php, performance, symfony, twig

In my symfony application, I use voters to check if users can access some features.

Now, I have a navbar where the menus are displayed or hidden according to those rights.

This navbar alone renders in about 2 seconds. That's a lot added to every page.
If I comment out the render_controller of the navbar, I gain 2 seconds. If I return true at the top of every voter is_granted method, I gain 1.5 seconds.

How can I solve this ? Using cache ? not using voters ? simplifying my voters ? Is it not a best practice to use voters? even if symfony has to check attributes against the list of all attributes?

My navbar generator:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Menu;

use AppBundle\Application\Core\ExplorerManager;
use AppBundle\Entity\User\Associate;
use AppBundle\Entity\User\Role;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Router;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authorization\AuthorizationChecker;
use Symfony\Component\Translation\Translator;

class MenuBuilder
{
    /**
     * @var Router
     */
    private $router;
    /**
     * @var Translator
     */
    private $translator;
    /**
     * @var AuthorizationChecker
     */
    private $authorizationChecker;

    /**
     * @param Router $router
     * @param Translator $translator
     * @param AuthorizationChecker $authorizationChecker
     */
    public function __construct(Router $router, Translator $translator, AuthorizationChecker $authorizationChecker)
    {
        $this->router = $router;
        $this->translator = $translator;
        $this->authorizationChecker = $authorizationChecker;
    }

    public function getFrontendHeaderMenuItems($isAuthenticated)
    {
        $menuItems = array(
            array(
                'title' => 'pricing',
                'route' => 'cms',
                'route_parameters' => array('dir' => 'general', 'page' => 'foodmeup_premium')
            ),
//            array(
//                'title' => 'recipes',
//                'route' => 'explore',
//                'route_parameters' => array('object' => ExplorerManager::RECETTE)
//            ),
            array(
                'title' => 'blog',
                'route' => 'explore',
                'route_parameters' => array('object' => ExplorerManager::BLOG)
            ),
            array(
                'title' => 'contact',
                'route' => 'message_foodmeup'
            )
        );

        if (false == $isAuthenticated) {
            $menuItems[] = array(
                'title' => 'login',
                'route' => 'login'
            );
        }

        $menuItems = $this->generateMenuRoutes(
            $menuItems,
            'frontend_bars',
            array()
        );

        return $menuItems;
    }

    public function getBackendLeftSidebarMenuItems()
    {
        $menuItems = array(
            array(
                'title' => 'dashboard',
                'icon' => 'th-large',
                'route' => 'dashboard'
            ),
            array(
                'title' => 'administration',
                'icon' => 'star',
                'is_granted' => Role::ROLE_ADMIN,
                'children' => array(
                    array(
                        'title' => 'dashboard',
                        'route' => 'admin_dashboard',
                    ),
                    array(
                        'title' => 'moderation',
                        'route' => 'moderate_posts',
                    ),
                    array(
                        'title' => 'users',
                        'route' => 'switch_user',
                        'is_granted' => Role::ROLE_SUPERADMIN,
                    ),
                    array(
                        'title' => 'subscriptions',
                        'route' => 'grant_partner_subscription',
                        'is_granted' => Role::ROLE_SUPERADMIN,
                    )
                )
            ), array(
                'title' => 'ingredients',
                'icon' => 'flask',
                'children' => array(
                    array(
                        'title' => 'explore_ingredients',
                        'route' => 'explore',
                        'route_parameters' => array('object' => ExplorerManager::CONSOMMABLE)
                    ),
                    array(
                        'title' => 'my_ingredients',
                        'route' => 'user_ingredients_display',
                        'is_granted' => Associate::READ_INGREDIENT
                    ), array(
                        'title' => 'create_import',
                        'route' => 'edit_ingredient',
                        'is_granted' => Associate::EDIT_INGREDIENT
                    ), array(
                        'title' => 'stock',
                        'route' => 'set_ingredient_stock',
                        'is_granted' => Associate::READ_STOCK,
                    ), array(
                        'title' => "buying_cost",
                        'route' => 'parameter_cost',
                        'is_granted' => Associate::READ_COST,
                    )
                )
            ), array(
                'title' => 'recipes',
                'icon' => 'birthday-cake',
                'children' => array(
                    array(
                        'title' => 'explore_recipes',
                        'route' => 'explore',
                        'route_parameters' => array('object' => ExplorerManager::RECETTE)
                    ),
                    array(
                        'title' => 'my_recipes',
                        'route' => 'user_recipes_display',
                        'is_granted' => Associate::READ_RECIPE
                    ), array(
                        'title' => 'create',
                        'route' => 'edit_recipe',
                        'is_granted' => Associate::EDIT_RECIPE
                    ), array(
                        'title' => 'print',
                        'route' => 'print_recipes',
                        'is_granted' => Associate::READ_RECIPE
                    )
                )
            ), array(
                'title' => 'plannings',
                'icon' => 'tasks',
                'is_granted' => array(Associate::READ_PLANNING, Associate::EDIT_PLANNING, Associate::DELETE_PLANNING),
                'children' => array(
                    array(
                        'title' => 'my_plannings',
                        'route' => 'display_plannings',
                        'is_granted' => Associate::READ_PLANNING
                    ), array(
                        'title' => 'my_models',
                        'route' => 'display_plannings',
                        'route_parameters' => array('isModel' => true),
                        'is_granted' => Associate::READ_PLANNING
                    ), array(
                        'title' => 'create_planning',
                        'route' => 'edit_planning',
                        'is_granted' => array(Associate::EDIT_PLANNING, Associate::CREATE_MODEL)
                    )
                )
            ), array(
                'title' => 'orders',
                'icon' => 'phone',
                'is_granted' => array(Associate::READ_ORDER, Associate::EDIT_ORDER, Associate::EDIT_ORDER, Associate::DELETE_ORDER),
                'children' => array(
                    array(
                        'title' => 'my_orders',
                        'route' => 'display_planning_orders',
                        'is_granted' => Associate::READ_ORDER
                    ), array(
                        'title' => 'automatic_order',
                        'route' => 'automatic_order',
                        'is_granted' => Associate::EDIT_ORDER
                    ), array(
                        'title' => 'edit_order',
                        'route' => 'edit_order',
                        'is_granted' => Associate::EDIT_ORDER
                    )
                )
            ), array(
                'title' => 'suppliers',
                'icon' => 'truck',
                'is_granted' => array(Associate::EDIT_SUPPLIER, Associate::READ_SUPPLIER, Associate::DELETE_SUPPLIER),
                'children' => array(
                    array(
                        'title' => 'my_suppliers',
                        'route' => 'display_suppliers',
                        'is_granted' => Associate::READ_SUPPLIER
                    ), array(
                        'title' => 'select',
                        'route' => 'user_supplier_select',
                        'is_granted' => Associate::EDIT_SUPPLIER
                    ), array(
                        'title' => 'create',
                        'route' => 'edit_organization',
                        'route_parameters' => array('category_slug' => 'fournisseur-de-consommables'),
                        'is_granted' => Associate::EDIT_SUPPLIER
                    )
                )
            ), array(
                'title' => 'teams',
                'icon' => 'users',
                'is_granted' => array(Associate::EDIT_TEAM, Associate::READ_TEAM, Associate::DELETE_TEAM, Associate::MANAGE_RIGHTS),
                'children' => array(
                    array(
                        'title' => 'my_teams',
                        'route' => 'teams_display',
                    ), array(
                        'title' => 'worker_parameter',
                        'route' => 'worker_parameter',
                        'is_granted' => Associate::EDIT_TEAM,
                    )
                )
            )
        );

        $menuItems = $this->generateMenuRoutes($menuItems, 'backend_bars', array());

        return $menuItems;
    }

    private function generateMenuRoutes(Array $menuItems, $domain, $isGranted)
    {
        foreach ($menuItems as $key => $menuItem) {
            if (array_key_exists('is_granted', $menuItems[$key])) {
                $rights = is_array($menuItems[$key]['is_granted']) ? $menuItems[$key]['is_granted'] : array($menuItems[$key]['is_granted']);

                $rights = array_map(function ($right) {
                    return $this->authorizationChecker->isGranted($right);
                }, $rights);

                if (in_array(true, $rights) == false) {
                    unset($menuItems[$key]);
                    continue;
                }
            }

            if (array_key_exists('route', $menuItems[$key])) {
                $menuItems[$key]['uri'] = $this->router->generate($menuItems[$key]['route'], array_key_exists('route_parameters', $menuItems[$key]) ? $menuItems[$key]['route_parameters'] : array());
            } else {
                $menuItems[$key]['uri'] = '#/';
            }

            $menuItems[$key]['title'] = $this->translator->trans($menuItems[$key]['title'], array(), $domain);
            if (array_key_exists('children', $menuItems[$key])) {
                $menuItems[$key]['children'] = $this->generateMenuRoutes($menuItems[$key]['children'], $domain, $isGranted);
            }
        }

        return $menuItems;
    }

    public function extractTitles(Array $menuItems)
    {
        $titles = array();

        foreach ($menuItems as $key => $menuItem) {
            $titles[] = $menuItems[$key]['title'];
            if (array_key_exists('children', $menuItems[$key])) {
                $titles = array_merge($titles, $this->extractTitles($menuItems[$key]['children']));
            }
        }

        return $titles;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can try [Blackfire](https://blackfire.io/) for finding performance issue.

Answer (score 1):

Voters have performance drawbacks. So if you need a higher performance then it's better to use ACL or optimize voters loading, because symfony loops over all voters when each security check is performed.

Lets's suppose you have 30 links in a menu and there are 20 voters. When you check access to all links in 1 loop then symfony will call voters 600 times (the most of them will return Voter::ACCESS_ABSTAIN immediately, but it still takes time and in you case it takes too much time).

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**
Symfony added voter caching for skipping call unneeded voters if new functions supportsAttribute or supportsType  returned false once.

https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-5-4-faster-security-voters